# Email format change when viewing on RTL langauge settings in gmail

Tags: html, node.js, email, gmail, html-email

I got an issue where if I am sending email with nodemailer + handlebars, the email will look okay if my Gmail language is set to English, but if I change the language, specifically to a right to left language the format get all messed up.

I tried:

1. `<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
2. `<meta name="Content-Language" content="en-US" />`
3. `body { text-align: left; direction: ltr; }`

Nothing helped, how can it be fixed? to tell Gmail to render the mail the same (English) no matter what's the Gmail language setting is.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by adding
`<body dir="ltr">`

the `dir="ltr"` fixed it